# Chromecast & Air for Android Apps (AS3)

Tags: android, actionscript-3, flash, air, chromecast

Anyone one know a simple way to use / intergrate a chromecast sender for my Air for Android Apps so they can cast directly to a TV.

I've done a few successful tests on webpages.
but as for intergrating the code into an entirely AS3 project, I don't know were to begin?  and I can't seem to find any docs on how to do this.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There in an Air Native Extension that handles this: [ANE-Chromecast on Github](https://github.com/renaudbardet/ANE-chromecast)

Answer (score 1):

The **ANE** on **Github** is not a solution (line 19 of `AirCast.as` specifically excludes Android).

More fundamentally, even after re-engineering the **ANE** to get around the original block, it is currently not possible to get a reference to `android.os.Bundle` (which is required) as the class is not reachable, no matter how many SDK jars you build into the **ANE**.

Until there is a means to get the bundle, then this call will always fail:

```
CastDevice mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(route.getExtras());
```

With:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/cast/CastDevice;
```

But if anybody can get around this, please let me know as I would dearly like to get there...