# Chromecast and ANE for AIR Android apps - Accessing android.os

Tags: android, air, chromecast, ane

I am trying to provide Chromecast support for an Android / AIR app.
A previous thread in stack overflow ( [Chromecast & Air for Android Apps (AS3)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27940185/chromecast-air-for-android-apps-as3/27948008#27948008) ) suggested that this could be supported by an ANE here ( https://github.com/renaudbardet/ANE-chromecast ).

However; it is not.

1. Line 19 of AirCast.as includes the comment "at first we only support iOS, will implement Android support when google does release the cast SDK" and line 23 explicitly blocks Android
2. The library is years old and unmaintained
3. When I tried using it as a base to work around the newer API, I quickly hit a roadblock when trying to access CastDevice Java class ( https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2292496 )

The problem I have is this;

1. In order to access CastDevice, I need to call CastDevice.getFromBundle

   CastDevice mSelectedDevice = CastDevice.getFromBundle(route.getExtras());
2. Although I have included all the SDK assets / classes needed for this call, CastDevice.getFromBundle depends on android.os.Bundle
3. There is no JAR I can use to add this to the AIR runtime so the ANE fails with

   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/cast/CastDevice;

As it stands, therefore, any attempt to use Chromecast with AIR and ANE on Android is a non-starter.

Is there any way to use Chromecast with AIR / Android that gets around this limitation? Either by finding a way to provide access to android.os (unlikely, I admit) or by an alternative setup structure that avoids the need for it?

Thanks,
G

Answer (score 0):

Although this is an old question, there is a new ANE which might help for iOS.

You can try it [here](https://github.com/mesmotronic/air-ane-chromecast)